# How to implement C# Rhino Security

Tags: c#, security, nhibernate, privileges, rhino-security

I am trying to implement Rhino Security, i have managed to find a couple tutorials but they do not give enough information to completely understand it, i was wondering if anyone knows of a good source where to learn about Rhino Security from. Or sugest alternatives for implementing security with NHibernate.

Is there some sort of documentation for any of the methods / classes within Rhino Security?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know there is no centralized documentation for Rhino.Security. The best tutorial I know is [this article by Artur Trosin](http://weblogs.asp.net/arturtrosin/archive/2009/04/02/rhino-tools-rhino-security-guide.aspx) (even though it's slightly outdated by now). [Winecellarmanager](http://code.google.com/p/winecellarmanager/) is a sample app that uses Rhino.Security. There's also a [admin UI for Rhino.Security](https://github.com/nexida/Rhino-Security-Administration), reading its source code might help. There was also some [talk about integrating Rhino.Security to Who Can Help Me](http://whocanhelpme.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=214319), but I don't know if it was finished. There's also an article about [integrating Rhino.Security to S#arp projects](http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2009/04/30/adding-rhino-security-support-to-s-arp-projects.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, am looking into this now, downloading the Rhino Security repository has helped as it includes the xunit tests, which sets up everything. The admin UI looks very promising as well. Thanks for this answer :)